# Error handling loop not functioning as expected

Tags: python, exception, valueerror

Very new to programming and I'm trying to write a to-do list program without referencing any books or videos, etc. Just trying to figure out all the logic on my own. I'm really stumped on why this function is not behaving how I am expecting it to:

```
def edit_todo(todos):
    show_todos(todos)

    invalid_input = True
    while invalid_input:
        edit_selection = int(input("Select which to-do to edit: "))
        try:
            if edit_selection > len(todos) or edit_selection < 1:
                print("That number is out of range. Please try again.")
        except ValueError:
            print("You must enter a valid selection. Please try again.")
    todos[edit_selection-1] = str(input("Enter the new to-do text: "))
    show_todos(todos)
```

When this function is called, I want to make sure the user is inputting a number that corresponds to an existing to-do from the to-do list (todos). The error handling seems to work properly for the index range, but if I enter say the letter 'm' then it just continues on and executes the main program loop outside of this function rather than activating the ValueError exception and prompting the user to enter a valid input.

I have stared at and tried to re-arrange and reconfigure this function, but no luck. What am I not seeing? Thanks for your help!

UPDATE:

Thanks for all of your help!!! The following version appears to be working as intended!

```
def edit_todo(todos):
    show_todos(todos)

    invalid_input = True
    while invalid_input:
        try:
            edit_selection = int(input("Select which to-do to edit: "))
            if edit_selection > len(todos) or edit_selection < 1:
                raise IndexError
        except ValueError:
            print("You must enter a valid to-do number. Please try again.")
        except IndexError:
            print("That number does not correspond to a to-do in the list. Please try again.")
        else:
            invalid_input = False
    todos[edit_selection-1] = str(input("Enter the new to-do text: "))
    show_todos(todos)
```

Comment: The `int(input(...))` statement is not inside the try block, so if you end up trying to call `int()` on a letter, that exception will not be caught.

Comment: Also, the first `print` should actually be `raise ValueError`. Printing a message doesn't trigger an error so your `try`/`except` block will never catch anything.

Comment: I'm not sure any of the code that _is_ in the try block can possibly raise ValueError, so that try block might be useless.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight. Why is a ValueError not immediately raised when I added int(input())? Shouldn't the user typing a non integer throw an error right away?